# Batch file as a service using srvany doesn't execute

Tags: batch-file, service, windows-services

I have a simple batch file which monitors other service. If the service is running, it checks whether dependent process is running or not. If not, it restarts the service. If the service is stopped, it stops the dependent process as well. The service actually triggers the process and then they are independent.

Batch file is as follows-

```
@echo off
:start
sc query MyService | find "STATE" | find "RUNNING"
    if errorlevel 1 WMIC process Where "CommandLine Like '%% -jar myjar.jar%%'" Call Terminate

WMIC process where caption="java.exe" get commandline | findstr "myjar.jar" > nul
    if errorlevel 1 sc stop MyService && sc start MyService 

Sleep 10
goto start
```

I don't want to run above batch file in an interactive cmd console, because anyone could close it. So, service is necessary. To create a service I used [this help](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Basis/How+To+Install+a+Batch+file+as+Windows+Service). I have followed the procedure correctly but it doesn't execute the batch file as it doesn't monitor the service (I've tested it).

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise OS and obviously administrator user.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the way I've created the service?

If any clarifications needed, please ask and your help is appreciated.

Comment: The devil will be in the details. If srvany isn't launching the batch file, then something is wrong with that setup. Also, check the event logs for errors starting the service.